# Javascript plugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, callback

I'm pretty new to javascript and jQuery. I'm stuck trying to make jQuery.fallr work inside my callback function.

```
$("#test").click(function() {
    $.post("<?php echo site_url() . 'controller/method'; ?>", $('#form').serializeArray(), function( data ) {
        if(data=="notok") {
            jQuery.fallr('show', {
            content : '<p><?php echo $this->lang->line("ok"); ?></p>',
            icon    : 'error'
            });
        }
    });
```

console doesn't give me any error but it isn't showing the dialog either. Do I need to make something before the jQuery.fallr()?

Comment: According to the [Readme](https://github.com/faisalman/fallr-js), the syntax is `jQuery.fallr.show`. Are you sure you can use it in the way you did?

Comment: if i console log the data it shows notok @Taplar

Comment: Alright, so it's not an ajax issue.